# SolrCore Initialization Failures, sometimes it says, "sorry, no dataimport-handler defined!" and sometimes it throws the error below

Tags: java, solr

SolrCore Initialization Failures, sometimes it says, "sorry, no dataimport-handler defined!" and sometimes it throws the error below

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading class 'org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler'
```

Been stuck here for days, and no this isn't HomeWork, just a student trying to learn how Natural Language Processing is done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your class path , it seems thats DataImportHandler is not added in  classpath.

do check the solrConfig.xml for below

```
<lib dir="../../../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
```